# How to infer coordinates from few fixed points of unknown projection

Tags: python, geolocation, map-projections

I have around 300 (x, y) values (integers) of points on a map (unknown projection). I also have 6 points (x, y, latitude, longitude) which I want to use to infer the latitude and longitude for the other points.

I have already tried just inferring how many units on the map correspond to what kind of latitude or longitude distance but I have realised that this falls short of a solution because there is no fixed mapping because this depends on the projection.

Answer (score 0):

Do all you can to find the projection. With that and your 6 reference points or less you can easily calibrate the map.

Otherwise, you can only obtain a rough approximation. In that case:

You can triangulate your map using the 6 known points and interpolate lat/lon inside each triangle.

You can also use thin-plate splines (2-d splines) to obtain an approximate x,y <-> lat/lon transformation.

If the map has lat/lon lines (or UTM lines) you can project round lat/lon values on the map's grid to validate your results, and adjust them if necessary.

You can also improve your collection of calibration points (x, y, lat, lon) by identifying points in Google Earth, Bing maps... (I used to physically visit points and get their GPS coordinates before the Google Earth era...)